# Prove the orthogonality of vector spherical harmonics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, harmonic-functions, general-relativity, legendre-polynomials

We define

$S_a^{lm} = \Big( - \frac{1}{\sin \theta} Y^{lm}_{,\varphi}, \sin \theta\ Y^{lm}_{,\theta} \Big)$

$Y_a^{lm} = \Big( Y^{lm}_{,\theta}, Y^{lm}_{,\varphi} \Big)$

to be the axial vector spherical harmonics and the polar vector spherical harmonics, respectively, and $Y^{lm}$ are the scalar ones, while, $_{,\theta}$ indicates the differentiation with respect to $\theta$ and similarly for $\varphi$.
I have to prove on the two-sphere $S^2$ that they are orthogonal. I was able to prove that the scalar product on the two-sphere of

$\gamma^{ab}\langle Y_a^{l'm'},Y_b^{l'm'} \rangle = \int d{\varphi}d{\theta} \sin \theta {Y_a^{*}}^{l'm'}Y_b^{l'm'} \gamma^{ab}  = \delta^{ll'} \delta^{mm'}l(l+1) = \gamma^{ab}\langle S_a^{l'm'},S_b^{l'm'} \rangle$,

where $\gamma^{ab} = \text{diag}(1,1/ \sin^2 \theta)$ is the inverse of the metric on $S^2$, by using the relations

$\gamma^{ab} Y^{lm}_{:ab} = Y^{lm}_{,\theta \theta} + \cot \theta Y^{lm}_{,\theta} + \sin^{-2} \theta Y^{lm}_{,\varphi \varphi} = - l(l+1) Y^{lm}$,

where $:$ is the covariant derivative on $S^2$, and

$\langle {Y^{l'm'}} Y^{lm} \rangle = \delta^{ll'} \delta^{mm'}$,

but now I am struggling because it seems I cannot use the latter. Indeed, I have to compute

$\gamma^{ab}\langle Y_a^{l'm'}, S_b^{lm} \rangle  = \int d\theta d \varphi \sin \theta (-{Y^{*}_{,\theta}}^{l'm'}\frac{1}{\sin \theta} Y^{lm}_{,\varphi} + {Y^{*}_{,\varphi}}^{l'm'}\frac{1}{\sin \theta}Y^{lm}_{,\theta}) = \int d \theta d \varphi ({Y^{*}_{,\varphi}}^{l'm'}Y^{lm}_{,\theta} - {Y^{*}_{,\theta}}^{l'm'}Y^{lm}_{,\varphi}),$

and this should be 0, but why? Am I missing some parity relation of spherical harmonics?

Comment: I forgot yo say that * is the complex conjugation

Comment: What happens after integration by parts? I think boundary terms vanish, while integrand also vanishes.

Comment: So, you are saying that
${Y^{*}}^{l'm'} Y_{,\theta}^{lm} |_{0}^{2 \pi} = 0 = {Y^{*}}^{l'm'} Y_{,\varphi}^{lm} |_{0}^{\pi} $,

right?